# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC and Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I keep running into problems creating a Windows Azure Cloud Service and trying to add an MVC 2 (which ends up being an MVC 3) Web Role. Initially it says MVC 2 but I was really hoping to get an MVC 3 app. Then it says that it will be an MVC 3 Web Role. Once I've gone through the steps, I get the following error:

> Cannot add the item because the item
>   to add it to is not a solution folder
>   or the solution.

This happens no matter what I do to add it. Worker Role, standard Web Role work fine. Only the MVC 3 Web Role fails. Is there something special that I need to do to get this to work? Or how do I get started making an MVC 3 Azure app and combining it with a Worker Role?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDK 1.3 will fix this (that using the MVC web role template when MVC 3 is installed doesn't work).  SDK 1.3 ships later this year.

Yes, for manually adding an MVC 3 web role, I think it works to create a new MVC 3 web app, mark the MVC binaries as "copy local" (since they're not GAC'd in the cloud), and then "add existing web role in solution" to hook it up as a web role for your project.  (What I described should be exactly what Jim's talking about in that blog post.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a great article: [How To Publish an ASP.NET MVC 3 App to Windows Azure](http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-publish-aspnet-mvc-3-app-to.html)

It is written for the ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post describes MVC2 on Azure but it should work with MVC3 as well:

[**Migrating an Existing ASP.NET App to run on Windows Azure**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx)